# How can I pass a directory name as an argument and output a list of files in it?

Tags: c, linux

This program should get a directory name as argument. I have a working piece of code that prints the filenames in a directory. But how can Ι pass the directory name here?

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  d = opendir(".");
  if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }
    closedir(d);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: `if ((d = opendir(argv[1])) != NULL) { /* work with d */ closedir(d); } else { perror(argv[1]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: You can pass an argument to your program at the command line. All arguments are provided to your code via the parameters of `main`. Read about the meaning of `argc` and `argv`. Then just pass the name you got to `opendir`

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `full path` as an argument to your program from the command line. In the `main` function of your code , there are two parameters : `int argc` & `char* argv[]`

`int argc` represents the number of arguments that your program received at its execution. The program's name is an argument by itself.

For example, in `./a.out argument1 argument2` , the `a.out` program's `argc` will be equal to 3.

`char* argv[]` is an array of `char*` all of which point to an argument.

In the previous example, `argv[0] == 'a.out'` , `argv[1] == 'argument1'` and `argv[2] == 'argument2'`

Now change your code as follows :

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  if(argc==2){
    char* path = argv[1];
    d = opendir(path);
    if (d) {
      while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
      }
      closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
  }else{
      printf("Wrong number of arguments");
      return 1;
  }
  
}
```

Then you should call the program as follows :

```
./name_of_the_program /path/to/the/dir
```

Comment: You should add the mandatory check whether there is an extra parameter available at all. And some explanation why index `1` is used would probably also help the OP.

Comment: You're wright, I updated the code

Comment: `Wrong number of arguments` sounds like an error message.  `fprintf(stderr, "...");`